# modificar mensajes de excepciones en postgresql

Tags: postgresql

como puedo cambiar los mensajes que me genera postgresql por defecto.
Ejemplo errorcode 42501 permission denied for relation usuarios
qu salga errorcode 42501 no tiene permisos

Comment: No creo que se pueda. De ser necesario, es tu responsabilidad interceptar los errores cuando ocurren y presentar un mensaje diferente.

Comment: lo que puedes hacer es cambiar el idioma es postgres para que vea los errores en español https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/locale.html

Comment: como puedo interceptar los errores.
tengo que hacerlos en cada funcion que realice o puedo crear una generica que siempre me capture dichos errores ?

Comment: Recuerdo haber leído que en Postgresql puedes cambiar el idioma de los mensajes. Cambiar los mensajes mismos, como ya se ha comentado, creo que no se puede. Una aproximación interesante podría ser construir tu propia clase en la cual declaras los mensajes a mostrar según los códigos de error. Entonces, cuando se lanza un error o una excepción, capturas el código y obtienes el mensaje desde tu clase `ErrorHelper`. Yo tengo algo así, pero para otro tipo de errores, en una app Android.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer lo puedes hacer modificando los siguientes parametros:

```
SET lc_messages TO 'es_MX.UTF-8';
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191428/change-language-of-system-and-error-messages-in-postgresql

Comment: ¿Qué es el parámetro `lc_messages`? ¿Qué es lo que hace y dónde se pone?

Comment: Son una serie de parámetros que tiene el abreviatura LC de Locale Support que según la documentación  nos dice: El soporte local se refiere a una aplicación que respeta las preferencias culturales con respecto a los alfabetos, la clasificación, el formato de números, etc.